# Website carousel stops working when second one is added

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a website with a simple non-controlable carousel with the following code before the /head tag

script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">/script
script src="jquery.carouFredSel-6.0.4-packed.js" type="text/javascript">/script

I have the jquery-1.8.2.min.js and jquery.carouFredSel-6.0.4-packed.js files downloaded in my folder.

It works perfectly, but when I add a second carousel, this second one works but the first one doesn't.

I've created the second carousel downloading the files: jquery-2.1.0.min.js and application.js.

Instead the case of the first carousel, in the second one I put the following instructions inside the  tag, in the div element which defines the carousel-

script src="jquery-2.1.0.min.js">/script
script src="application.js">/script

It is due to having two different js files?

Many thanks for taking the time of reading my question and sorry for my english and my lack of knowledge

Comment: Can you post your code or a link to your code so we can help you?

Comment: Can you provide us with JSFiddle so we can actually help you?

Answer (score 2):

I think mostly thats because of html-tag conflicts. Make sure, they have different ID's and dont overwrite each other.